# How would I convert an NSMutableArray filled of UNIX dates to standard dates?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, nsarray

I have an NSMutableArray filled up of UNIX dates (1305410327), and I want to convert all of them to readable dates like Fri, 06 Feb 2009 07:28:06 +0000. I'm so lost and this is the code I have:

```
NSDate *fulltime = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[time objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

But gives me next error when compiling:

```
error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:'
```

So I don't know how to make it work. Thanks all in advance! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

zad0xsis,

You need to convert the NSNumber into an NSTimeInterval. Here is a fix to your code:

```
NSDate *fulltime = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970: 
                    [[time objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] doubleValue]];
```

Andrew